# mysql get last 3 row and compare record

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table how can I get last 3 row to compare and get count number?

Example: table

```
id| name
=========
1 | Apple
2 | Orange
3 | Kiwi
4 | Banana
5 | Apple
6 | Banana
7 | Apple
```

How can I get Apple count number last 3 row?

Many thanks

Comment: what do you meanf for last 3 rows .. in sql the row must ordered explicitally .. so explain better how do you want obtain the last 3 rows... you mean order by id?

Comment: order by id to get last 3 rows, In this case I want to get  row 5-7 and count apple in this 3 rows.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Yes, this is homework. In this case I should be get 2, because I want to get count  5-7 row have apple. but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a temp table for select the last 3 rows and the group by the resulting rows

```
 select name, count(*) from 
    (select name,id 
     from my_table 
     order by id desc limit 3)  t
group by name
```

Comment: 'As' should be removed from query. It should read like select name from t ...

Comment: @BikashP   thanks done ..

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear, but if I understand correctly;
Check the queries and results:

## Query - 1:

```
SELECT 
    id, name, COUNT(*) AS total_row
FROM
   furits
GROUP BY NAME ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3;
```

## Result - 1:

```
id| name   | total_row  
======================
4 | Banana | 2
3 | Kiwi   | 1
2 | Orange | 1
```

## Query - 2:

```
SELECT 
    id, name, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
   furits
GROUP BY NAME ORDER BY id DESC;
```

## Result - 2:

```
id| name   | total_row  
======================
4 | Banana | 2
3 | Kiwi   | 1
2 | Orange | 1
1 | Apple  | 3
```

## Query - 3:

```
SELECT 
    id, name, COUNT(*) AS total_row
FROM
   furits 
WHERE 
    name = 'Apple'
GROUP BY NAME LIMIT 0,1;
```

## Result - 3:

```
id| name   | total_row  
======================
1 | Apple  | 3
```

I hope this help.